# Can't get bookmarklet to POST form with value

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

The form looks like this:

```
 <form action='localhost/test.php' method='post' target='test'>
 <input type='text' name='add_to_url' value='' />
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Go' />
 </form>
```

And I can't get anything to even come close.

Ideally the bookmarlet would use the current webpage URL as the add_to_url value, and then submit the form.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the url of current page you need to use location.href Javascript property.

To get started with developing bookmarklets, you can go through following links:
http://www.bookmarklets.com/tools/categor.html 
http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/

Also, you can search for bookmarklets Javascript code on [Search Bookmarklets](http://marklets.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Below is Javascript code to create a form and post it. You use it like `get2post('http://site.com?a=1&c=2');`

Here is a simple bookmarklet generator, or google for others: http://chris.zarate.org/bookmarkleter

```
function get2post(u, t) { // u = url, t = target
    var p = u.split('?')[0];
    var q = u.split('?')[1].split('&');
    var d = document;
    var f = d.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('action', p);
    f.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
    f.setAttribute('target', t || '_parent');
    f.style.display = 'none';
    for (i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        var e = d.createElement("input");
        var param = q[i].split('=');
        e.name = param[0];
        if ( param.length >= 2 ) e.value = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);        
        f.appendChild(e);
    }
    d.body.appendChild(f);
    f.submit();
}
```